# Passing lists with any type from parent to child component on razor page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I am trying to pass a list from the parent to the child component so that the child component can process with the list.
Then, the user can click the button on the child component to process the list received from the parent.

**Error**
`cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Test.Data.Class1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Type>'`

**Class**

```
public class Class1
{
    public string name {get; set;} = string.Empty;
    public int id {get; set;} 
}
```

**Parent Razor Page**

```
@if (myList.Any() != false)
{
    <Component1 childList="@myList"/>
}

@code{
    List<Class1> myList = new List<Class1>();
    //add data into myList
    ... 
}
```

**Child Component**

```
<button onclick="@childFunction">Process List</button>

@code{

    [Parameter]
    public List<Type> childList{get; set;} = null!;

    public void childFunction()
    {
         ProcessList(childList);
    }

    public static void ProcessList<T>(List<T> childList)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: For performance's sake use a service that is injected into the components that contains the list. You will thank me.

Comment: The general sound rule Brian is advocating here is: Get your data out of your components.  If you're unsure how, ask. -  @BrianParker - agree absolutely

Comment: See this answer to another question today doing exactly what Brian advocates - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74531023/13065781

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding generic component, then you need to add `@typeparam Type` in `Component1.razor`

```
@typeparam Type
<button onclick="@childFunction">Process List</button>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public List<Type> childList { get; set; } = null!;

    public void childFunction() => ProcessList(childList);

    public static void ProcessList<T>(List<T> childList)
    {
    }

}
```