# Blazor bind values from 1 class to NavMenu.razor

Tags: blazor, bind

I'm new to Blazor, hoping for your help.

I initiate a new project with VS 2022, .Net 6

With the default project created.

Step 1:

I add to the project 1 Class as follows:

```
namespace BlazorApp1
{
    public class ClassNumber
    {
        public static int txtnumber = 0;
    }
}
```

---

Step 2:
On the page "Counter.razor" I pass the parameter to Class
"ClassNumber.txtnumber = currentCount;"

```
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
       ClassNumber.txtnumber = currentCount;
    }
}
```

---

Step 3:
Now I want this txtnumber value to update to "NavMenu.razor" page when I change Click

I have tried the following to no avail ("NavMenu.razor")

```
.........
<div class="nav-item px-3">
<NavLink class="nav-link">
<span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Number change : @ClassNumber.txtnumber
</NavLink>
</div>
...........
```

[This is the picture I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmBBo.png)

Hope someone can help me with a simple example.

Sorry for my bad english.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The classic problem with the out-of-the-box template.  "Quick and dirty" where "and Dirty" comes back to haunt us as we extent functionality and scope.

The solution is *Separation of Concerns*.  Get the data out of the Component and UI which is what you have started to do.

Separate the Data from the UI.

```cs
public class CounterData
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

A service to manage the data:

```cs
public class CounterService
{
    public CounterData Data { get; private set; } = new();
    public event EventHandler? StateChanged;

    public void Increment()
    {
        Data.Counter++;
        this.StateChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Register the service in Program:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<CounterService>();
```

Update the Counter route component:

```cs
@page "/counter"
@inject CounterService Service
<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @this.Service.Data.Counter</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {

    // No need to call StateHasChanged as the ComponentBase UI handler does it for us
    private void IncrementCount()
        => this.Service.Increment();
}
```

And NavMenu:

```cs
@inject CounterService Service

//.....
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter @(this.Service.Data.Counter)
            </NavLink>
        </div>

//....
@code {

//....
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // register a handler on the counter service StateChanged
        this.Service.StateChanged += this.OnCounterChanged;
    }

    // This is the event handler to update the component when the counter changes
    private void OnCounterChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // unhook our handler from the counter service StateChanged
        // This will get called when the Renderer disposes of the component 
        // when it's no longer in the RenderTree 
        this.Service.StateChanged -= this.OnCounterChanged;
    }
}
```

This is the basic Blazor "Notification" pattern.  You will use it a lot.

Comment: Hi, if this answers your question mark it as closed.