# Blazor OnParametersSet is not called after parameter value is being updated

Tags: razor, blazor, maui

I think I must have missed something here... I thought OnParametersSet would be called if I assign a new value to a parameter but it seems it's not the case. I'm trying to make a component re-render each time I assign it a new value to one of it's parameter.

For example, the below is page conatining "Clock" component. Every second, I update the parameter value.

```
@code {

    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public Timer Updater { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        this.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);

        this.Updater = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        Updater.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
        Updater.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        this.Duration = this.Duration.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
        Debug.WriteLine($"New Duration is {this.Duration.ToString()}");
    }
}

<Clock Value="@this.Duration" />
```

The below is the clock razor component.

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public TimeSpan Value { get; set; }
}

<div class="clock">
    <div class="minutes">@this.Value.Minutes</div>
    <div class="min-sec-separator">:</div>
    <div class="seconds">@this.Value.Seconds</div>
</div>
```

It will be really appreciated if someone could point me out what I am missing here.

Give the value is TimeSpan, I expected this should just work without any intervention.

Comment: try calling `StateHasChanged()` when `Duration` is changed

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try(parent):

```
@using System.Timers

@code {

    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public Timer Updater { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);

        this.Updater = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        Updater.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
        Updater.Enabled = true;
        base.OnInitialized();

    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        this.Duration = this.Duration.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
        StateHasChanged();
        Console.WriteLine($"New Duration is {this.Duration.ToString()}");
    }
}

<Clock Value="@this.Duration" />
```

And the Clock.razor(child):

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public TimeSpan Value { get; set; }
}

<div class="clock">
    <div class="minutes">@this.Value.Minutes</div>
    <div class="min-sec-separator">:</div>
    <div class="seconds">@this.Value.Seconds</div>
</div>
```

https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/mmFmbRvB17tQXjRy37

For explanation please see @MrCakaShaunCurtis answer.

Comment: if I understand correct, StateHasChanged() at parent level means I'm re-rendering the entire parent component including all the child components of it correct? I only want to re-render Clock component by updating it's value so that other child components won't be bothered with this rendering request...

Comment: @maciek - the reason that no rendering occurs is because `OnTimerElapsed` is a normal event handler, not a UI event - see my answer below for more detail.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis You are right here. I tried it out https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GmlmbSOX26iuxRWS02 and it does not work as I imagined. I edited my answer and added a reference to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Buga's answer is correct, but you need to understand why.

`ComponentBase` implements `IHandleEvent`.  When this interface is implemented all UI driven events call the `IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync` method, passing in the handler and the event arguments. The `ComponentBase` implementation calls `StateHaschanged` when (if the handler is async and yields) and after it executes the handler.

However, `OnTimerElapsed` is just a normal event handler, so there's no automated calling of `StateHasChanged`.  It's one of the few occasions you need to manually call it.

which handles all UI driven events.

Comment: Thanks for additional explanation @MrC. What's still unclear to me is what happened to "[Parameter] public TimeSpan Value {get; set;}" itself. I thought that it would detect the value being assigned to it and causes the clock component itself initiate a new rendering or at least call OnParametersSet... but none happened.

Comment: There's not automated process here.  When the parent renders, the renderer checks each child's "ParameterList" to determine whether any have changed and then calls  `SetParametersAsync` on any child where a change "may" have occured.   To drive change automatically, move the timer into a service and use the Notification pattern - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69562295/13065781

Comment: Here's another similar answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74530150/blazor-bind-values-from-1-class-to-navmenu-razor

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the parameter on `OnTimerElapsed`, you're only changing the value of a local field. The parameter is set when the component is rendered.
The component will be rendered when the state will change.

You can trigger the state change by calling `StateHasChanged()` when you need it.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. I kinda hoped I don't need to do the StateHasChanged() at the parent component but the clock component would detect as "Value" is a parameter for that component... I could be wrong but wouldn't this essentially re-render the entire parent component meaning it will be not just clock but everything else belong to this parent?

Comment: call a method on the clock, and that method can call `StateHasChanged` on the clock only