C# Blazor: Splitting a razor file
I have a Blazor component which stores data that should be displayed in two tables.
The related razor file contains HTML markup for the two tables which show same data in different ways:
DataComponent.razor.cs contains Components code:
public sealed partial class DataComponent : ComponentBase {...}

DataComponent.razor contains HTML markup for two tables
@if (_showTableA)
{
    <Table>A...</Table>
}
else
{
    <Table>B...</Table>
}

The HTML markup (it uses MudBlazor library) for the tables access public and private members of the component and is rather long and complex.
Now I want to move the markup to two separate razor files, one for table A and second for table B, so that DataComponent.razor just includes them, something like:
@if (_showTableA)
{
    <TableA/>
}
else
{
    <TableB/>
}

I tried two new components and included them with this code in DataComponent.razor:
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <TableA/>
</CascadingValue>

But it seems that new components cannot access private members of DataComponent with this approach.
I also read about Blazor RenderFragments, but examples like these
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-9.0
or
How do we create a reusable RenderFragment in a separate code file?
show HTML markup and code in one file whereas I need two markup files that access same component.
So my question is: How could I split my markup into two razor files which can be included in main razor file DataComponent.razor and access my DataComponent? Or is there a better approach for separating the markup?

IMO it's simpler just to pass parameters from DataComponent down to each new table wrapper component.

Basically, get the data out of your components.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74530150/blazor-bind-values-from-1-class-to-navmenu-razor for a simple example.  This <CascadingValue Value="this"> is in general bad practice.  Cascade the data and required functionality in a separate class.

You are on the right track but you shouldn't try to pass parental component as a cascading parameter - isolate data you want to render and pass it down to table component.
Alternatively you can create base partial table class (e.g. DataComponentTable.cs) that would be using the same logic to obtain data for TableA.razor and TableB.razor components.
